# Solving a three variable LP graphically to show a case where there is no feasible solution

Tags: graphing-functions, linear-programming

> John will spend £5 of his Christmas money on plain and milk
>   chocolates.
>
> He can buy boxes at £2 each. These contain 25 plain and 25 milk
>   chocolates.
>
> He can buy single plain chocolates at 6p each and loose milk
>   chocolates at 7p each.
>
> John wants to have at least twice as many milk as plain chocolates.
>
> John wishes to maximize the number of chocolates he can buy subject to the constraints.

From that problem, I decided on the three variables:

- $x$ for the number of loose plain chocolates
- $y$ for the number of loose milk chocolates
- $z$ for the number of boxes

And the following constraints:

$$2z + 0.06x + 0.07y \le 5 $$

$$y \ge 2x + 25z $$

To maximize:

$$50z + x + y$$

The question asks for a graph to be drawn to show that if $z = 2$ there is no feasible solution to the problem.

Whilst being able to solve two-variable LPs, how would I go about solving this three-variable LP graphically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the natural constraints $x\geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0$ since supposedly you cannot sell them short.

You only have to solve it for $z=2$. Setting this, reduces LP to maximizing $x+y$ subject to $0.06x + 0.07y \leq 1$ (equivalently, $6x+7y \leq 100$ and $y \geq 2x+50$. There are in 2 variables, so can be drawn without a problem in the regular 2D graph.

**EDIT** To add intuition, with pure algebra, Note the constraints imply
$$
14x + 350 \leq 7y \leq 100 - 6x,
$$
which of course implies $14x+350 \leq 100-6x$, so $20x \leq -250$ or $x \leq -12.5$, which cannot be since $x \geq 0$...